# How to show a different directive on click angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am trying to show the left nav menu, once the menu is clicked from the header bar.
I have created two directives, one for header bar and one for menu. But when i clicked on the header bar menu button, the left nav menu should display. but currently it's not working.

this is what i tried:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('test.header.module', []);

    angular.module('test.header.module')
        .directive('header',header)
        .directive('menu', menu);

    function header($compile){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<header> <button ng-click="showMenu()"> Test Header </button> </header>'+
                      '<menu ng-if="menuS"></menu>',
            link: function(scope, element, attr){
                scope.showMenu = function(){
                    scope.menuS = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    header.$inject = ["$compile"];

    function menu(){
        return{
            restrict:'EA',
            require: '^header',
            template : '<h1 id="test">{{test}}</h1>',
            link : function(scope, element, attr){
                scope.test = "Test Left Nav";
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `require: '^header'` - it can't find the 'header' controller.  If you remove this your code works. Also, $compile is not needed.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('test.header.module', []);

    angular.module('test.header.module')
        .directive('header',header)
        .directive('menu', menu)
  
    function header(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div> <button ng-click="showMenu()"> Test Header </button> </div>'+
                      '<menu ng-if="menuS"></menu>',
            link: function(scope, element, attr){
                scope.showMenu = function(){
                    scope.menuS = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function menu(){
        return{
            restrict:'EA',
            template : '<h1 id="test">{{test}}</h1>',
            link : function(scope, element, attr){
                scope.test = "Test Left Nav";
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test.header.module">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.10"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header></header>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: $compile is not necessary so have removed it